# Local host yii gives this type of error : yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()

Tags: php, yii

> PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> PHP Startup: zip: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP compiled with module API=20131226
>   These options need to match
>   2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()

Webpage runs ok but at the end of page this errors come. i tried one method which remove these errors temporary which are written in terminal.

# pecl upgrade fileinfo # pecl upgrade memcache # pecl upgrade mhash # pecl upgrade readline

thanks in advance.

Comment: `PHP Core Warning` - So it's just PHP error, not related with Yii; Error states that your ZIP module of PHP is compiled with different version than your actual PHP. Have you recently downloaded this module?

Comment: yes i am new to yii and when i try code as given above to terminal then its work but temporary

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not compatible, It might be versions issue so please perform the following steps:

1. Update your PHP.
2. Update your modules (PHP extensions).

Here is how you can update your PHP extensions. You must either

- Check what your distribution provides
- Or use the pecl command, to
  re-download the sources of the extensions in question, and re-compile
  them.

First install it

```
pecl uninstall module_name
```

Then install it

```
pecl install module_name
```

Don't forget to restart the Apache.